# Where in the apartment to store isopropyl alcohol

Tags: alcohols, safety

I want to have some **99% isopropyl alcohol** for cleaning purposes and I'm wondering where to store it since in my apartment I don't have a storage room or much space.

I've read it needs to be air tight and away from light and heat.

Would it be ok to store it in the *cupboard under the sink* close to other regular cleaning products? There won't be much ventilation there.

Comment: You've probably bought that in a store. How do they keep it? I assume you're not storing hundreds of liters.

Comment: It's a small amout (< 1L), I just want to make sure it's safe. In the store they just have it on the shelves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a gallon or more, under the sink is good . I believe I have some under the kitchen sink and I know I have some under the bathroom sinks. My 16 oz isopropyl plastic bottles are 90 %.